# Using ClientLogin with Google Tasks client libraries

Tags: android, authentication, client, task

I wrote a test application for Android accessing Google Tasks with Client Libraries.
In Google Task's Developer's guide only `Oauth 2.0` authorization method is mentioned.

Does anybody know how to Authorize with `ClientLogin` method using client libraries?

Comment: This question looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219852/problem-with-accessing-google-tasks-with-client-login

Comment: Did you find out the ClientLogin service name for the tasks API?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to visit the "Getting Started with the Tasks API and OAuth 2.0 on Android" article. It offers a step-by-step guide for obtaining an OAuth 2.0 access token from the Android AccountManager, and making a request to the Google Tasks API.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android